# Is there any additively homomorphic schemes that can make range proof?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, zero-knowledge-proofs

I want to know whether there is any additively homomorphic schemes that can make a non-interactive range proof.

For example, I have a pair of public and private key pairs $(K_p,K_v)$ that satisfying a additively homomorphic schemes $E$, and I want to prove that the plaintext of $C=E_{K_p}(m)$ belongs to $[a,b]$, where $m, a$ and $b$ are both positive numbers. Is there any additively homomorphic schemes and non-interactive range proof scheme that I can use to prove the plaintext inside $C$ belongs to $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use Paillier encryption as the homomorphic encryption scheme, and prove the encrypted plaintext falls within a range.

An interactive protocol can be found in Appendix A of this paper: [Fast Secure Two-Party ECDSA Signing](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/552), by Yehuda Lindell, Crypto 2017.

A non-interactive protocol can be found in this paper: [Non-interactive Zero-Knowledge Arguments for Voting](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/J.Groth/ACNS05VoteProofFull.pdf), by Jens Groth, ACNS 2005.

Comment: Thank you, sir. But I notice that this scheme is a interactive range proof scheme. Do you know any scheme that is non-interactive or do you have any ideas to transfer this scheme to non-interactive?

Comment: @FelixLL see the modified answer.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I am not familiar with this paper. I think the range proof scheme of the second paper is for homomorphic commitment scheme instead of homomorphic encryption scheme by a quick look. I will read this paper in detail, or try to transfer the scheme of the first paper to non-interactive by Fiat–Shamir heuristic. I hope it works. Thank you again.